# Highlight and autocomplete code inside custom tags as PHP

Tags: phpstorm

I have `php` file. And I have `php` code inside custom tags:

```
[[MYKEYWORD
    $x  = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = $x + $y;
    echo $z;
]]
```

or

```
[[
    $x  = 1; $y = 2; $z = $x + $y;
    echo $z;
]]
```

For the moment *PhpStorm* defines it as plain text, but I need *PhpStorm* to highlight and autocomplete code inside these tags as `php` code.

How do I do that?

Comment: You may want to check the [IntelliLang](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/intellilang.html) section in help. I don't know if it can do what you want but it's the closest tool I can think of.

Comment: Very unlikely to be able to do that without coding some plugin that will add such custom PHP code delimiter...

Comment: @LazyOne  do you know how to do that with a plugin?

Comment: @SergeyMishin I have not coded any plugins for PhpStorm ... so nope. I do not even know how easy it would be to insert your custom delimiters into existing file type (code that is already handled by another plugin, I mean). But if you want to try it yourself: 1) http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html 2) http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/faq.html 3) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development

Comment: @LazyOne I think the easest way to solve the problem is to quit from company I work :D ... Thanks for links and your help